# Anonymous Types - How to dynamically create?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

I inherited some code that has syntax I don't understand but need to alter. The line that starts with `var data = new[]` appears to be an Anonymous Type?

How can I alter it into being dynamic instead of hard-coded to 3 records?

```
public JsonResult GetPieChartData()
{
    var myList = db.Database.SqlQuery<Dashboard>("EXEC [DBO].[uspDivisionDashboard2] {0}, {1}",
        Environment.UserName, "GUID").ToArray();

    var data = new[] 
    {
        //these will get overwritten below
        new { Name = "Row 1", Value = 1 },
        new { Name = "Row 2", Value = 2 },
        new { Name = "Row 3", Value = 3 },
    };  

    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in myList)
    {
        data[j] = new { Name = i.Stat, Value = i.Total };
        j++;
    }

    return Json(data);
}
```

I tried converting that into a dictionary but when it's passed to my google chart, I now get "no data" so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lambda expression to accomplish this:

```
var data2 = myList.Select(x => new { Name = x.Stat, Value = x.Total }).ToArray();

return Json(data2);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!  One correction = "x.Total" instead of "i.Total"

Comment: Corrected, glad to help :)